# how to validate input with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the ErrorFoundFlag approach to Show an error message for all fields that are in error at once.

I have tried:

```
function processInfo() {
  var errorFoundFlag = "N"; //Initialize variable to 'N'
  firstName = $("firstname").value;
  lastName = $("lastname").value;
  numPets = $("numpets").value;
  var message = "";

  if (firstName >= 0) {
    firstName = firstname.length;
    msg += "Please enter first name";
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }

  if (lastName >= 0) {
    lastName = lastname.length;
    msg += "Please enter last name";
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }
  if (numPets >= 0) {
    numPets = numpets.length;
    msg += "Please enter the number of pets you have";
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <span id="firstname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <span id="lastname_error"></span>
</p>

<p>
  How Many Pets do you have? (0-3):
  <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  <span id="numpets_error"></span>
</p>
```

I need the error message to appear next to the input boxes when no text is input. And when text is input, the error message should go away but it's not working for me.

for example:

if the 
Enter First Name: is blank... (Please Enter First Name) Would Appear 
but if the name is entered the error message should go away. and if the other two are blank but the first name is entered when they click submit there would be error messages showing for the ones left blank.

Comment: Why are you comparing names with `0`?

Comment: You should be using `if(lastName == "")`

Comment: What's the point of `firstName = firstname.length;`? `firstname` is a DOM element, it doesn't have a length. And why are you replacing the variable that holds the value with the length?

Comment: yea i had lastname==="" before but i changed it because it wasnt working and i added the 0 because i was trying different things to see if somethig would happen i know that isnt right tho

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, but making the *minimum* number of changes to get roughly what you're asking for could look something like the following.

First, to get the value with jQuery you'll want `val()` (instead of `value`): `$("#firstname").val()`.

Then simple references to the error `span`s (for example: `$("#firstname_error")`). These are cleared every time so the errors go away.

Then comparing the values `length` to `0` (note this could still be buggy, for example, an empty space would pass: `" "`).

Then console logging the `errorFoundFlag` to do as you need.

Finally, calling this method on each `input` change with `onchange`.

There are a number of improvements that can be made, but these were the minimum number of changes to get what you had working.

```js
function processInfo() {
  var errorFoundFlag = "N"; //Initialize variable to 'N'
  firstName = $("#firstname").val()
  lastName = $("#lastname").val();
  numPets = $("#numpets").val();
  firstNameError = $("#firstname_error");
  lastNameError = $("#lastname_error");
  numPetsError = $("#numpets_error");
  
  firstNameError.text("")
  lastNameError.text("")
  numPetsError.text("")

  if (firstName.length === 0) {
    firstNameError.text("Please enter first name");
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }

  if (lastName.length === 0) {
    lastNameError.text("Please enter last name");
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }

  if (numPets.length === 0) {
    numPetsError.text("Please enter the number of pets you have");
    errorFoundFlag = "Y";
  }
  
  console.log(errorFoundFlag)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" onchange="processInfo()" />
  <span id="firstname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" onchange="processInfo()" />
  <span id="lastname_error"></span>
</p>

<p>
  How Many Pets do you have? (0-3):
  <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1" onchange="processInfo()" />
  <span id="numpets_error"></span>
</p>
```